# How to add logo image in this bootstrap snippet

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

The code is taken from here https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/resize-amp-fixed-header-shrinking-header.

I need to add an image as logo and when it is checked it should redirect to homepage, how do I do that?

```js
/*!
 * classie v1.0.0
 * class helper functions
 * from bonzo https://github.com/ded/bonzo
 * MIT license
 * 
 * classie.has( elem, 'my-class' ) -> true/false
 * classie.add( elem, 'my-new-class' )
 * classie.remove( elem, 'my-unwanted-class' )
 * classie.toggle( elem, 'my-class' )
 */

/*jshint browser: true, strict: true, undef: true, unused: true */
/*global define: false */

(function(window) {

  'use strict';

  // class helper functions from bonzo https://github.com/ded/bonzo

  function classReg(className) {
    return new RegExp("(^|\\s+)" + className + "(\\s+|$)");
  }

  // classList support for class management
  // altho to be fair, the api sucks because it won't accept multiple classes at once
  var hasClass, addClass, removeClass;

  if ('classList' in document.documentElement) {
    hasClass = function(elem, c) {
      return elem.classList.contains(c);
    };
    addClass = function(elem, c) {
      elem.classList.add(c);
    };
    removeClass = function(elem, c) {
      elem.classList.remove(c);
    };
  } else {
    hasClass = function(elem, c) {
      return classReg(c).test(elem.className);
    };
    addClass = function(elem, c) {
      if (!hasClass(elem, c)) {
        elem.className = elem.className + ' ' + c;
      }
    };
    removeClass = function(elem, c) {
      elem.className = elem.className.replace(classReg(c), ' ');
    };
  }

  function toggleClass(elem, c) {
    var fn = hasClass(elem, c) ? removeClass : addClass;
    fn(elem, c);
  }

  var classie = {
    // full names
    hasClass: hasClass,
    addClass: addClass,
    removeClass: removeClass,
    toggleClass: toggleClass,
    // short names
    has: hasClass,
    add: addClass,
    remove: removeClass,
    toggle: toggleClass
  };

  // transport
  if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
    // AMD
    define(classie);
  } else {
    // browser global
    window.classie = classie;
  }

})(window);
```

```css
/* =Reset default browser CSS. Based on work by Eric Meyer: http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/index.html
-------------------------------------------------------------- */

html,
body,
div,
span,
applet,
object,
iframe,
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6,
p,
blockquote,
pre,
a,
abbr,
acronym,
address,
big,
cite,
code,
del,
dfn,
em,
font,
img,
ins,
kbd,
q,
s,
samp,
small,
strike,
strong,
sub,
sup,
tt,
var,
b,
u,
i,
center,
dl,
dt,
dd,
ol,
ul,
li,
fieldset,
form,
label,
legend,
table,
caption,
tbody,
tfoot,
thead,
tr,
th,
td {
  background: transparent;
  border: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}

body {
  line-height: 1;
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
  clear: both;
  font-weight: normal;
}

ol,
ul {
  list-style: none;
}

blockquote {
  quotes: none;
}

blockquote:before,
blockquote:after {
  content: '';
  content: none;
}

del {
  text-decoration: line-through;
}


/* tables still need 'cellspacing="0"' in the markup */

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
}

a img {
  border: none;
}


/* =Scss Variables
-------------------------------------------------------------- */


/* =Global
-------------------------------------------------------------- */

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: #3cb5f9;
  color: #505050;
  font-family: "Ubuntu", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 1.8;
}


/* Headings */

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
  line-height: 1;
  font-weight: 300;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #3cb5f9;
}

a:hover {
  color: #0793e2;
}


/* =Template
-------------------------------------------------------------- */

#wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#main {
  background-color: #fff;
  padding-top: 150px;
}

.container {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 30px;
}

section {
  padding: 60px 0;
}

section h1 {
  font-weight: 700;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

section p {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

section p:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

section.color {
  background-color: #3cb5f9;
  color: white;
}


/* =Info Bar
-------------------------------------------------------------- */

#info-bar {
  background-color: #3cb5f9;
}

#info-bar a {
  color: white;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px;
}

#info-bar a:hover {
  background-color: #0793e2;
}

#info-bar span.all-tutorials,
#info-bar span.back-to-tutorial {
  display: block;
  width: 50%;
}

#info-bar span.all-tutorials {
  float: left;
  text-align: left;
}

#info-bar span.back-to-tutorial {
  float: right;
  text-align: right;
}


/* =Header
-------------------------------------------------------------- */

header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 150px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 999;
  background-color: #0683c9;
  -webkit-transition: height 0.3s;
  -moz-transition: height 0.3s;
  -ms-transition: height 0.3s;
  -o-transition: height 0.3s;
  transition: height 0.3s;
}

header h1#logo {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 150px;
  line-height: 150px;
  float: left;
  font-family: "Oswald", sans-serif;
  font-size: 60px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: 400;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
  -ms-transition: all 0.3s;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}

header nav {
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
}

header nav a {
  line-height: 150px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  color: #9fdbfc;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 18px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
  -ms-transition: all 0.3s;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}

header nav a:hover {
  color: white;
}

header.smaller {
  height: 75px;
}

header.smaller h1#logo {
  width: 150px;
  height: 75px;
  line-height: 75px;
  font-size: 30px;
}

header.smaller nav a {
  line-height: 75px;
}


/* =Footer
-------------------------------------------------------------- */


/* =Extras
-------------------------------------------------------------- */

.clearfix:after {
  visibility: hidden;
  display: block;
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  height: 0;
}


/* =Media Queries
-------------------------------------------------------------- */

@media all and (max-width: 660px) {
  /* =Header
  -------------------------------------------------------------- */
  header h1#logo {
    display: block;
    float: none;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 100px;
    line-height: 100px;
    text-align: center;
  }
  header nav {
    display: block;
    float: none;
    height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
  header nav a {
    line-height: 50px;
    margin: 0 10px;
  }
  header.smaller {
    height: 75px;
  }
  header.smaller h1#logo {
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 40px;
    font-size: 30px;
  }
  header.smaller nav {
    height: 35px;
  }
  header.smaller nav a {
    line-height: 35px;
  }
}

@media all and (max-width: 600px) {
  .container {
    width: 100%;
  }
  #info-bar a {
    display: block;
  }
  #info-bar span.all-tutorials,
  #info-bar span.back-to-tutorial {
    width: 100%;
  }
  #info-bar span.all-tutorials,
  #info-bar span.back-to-tutorial {
    float: none;
    text-align: center;
  }
  #info-bar span.all-tutorials {
    border-bottom: solid 1px #0793e2;
  }
}
```

```html
<script>
  function init() {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', function(e) {
      var distanceY = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop,
        shrinkOn = 300,
        header = document.querySelector("header");
      if (distanceY > shrinkOn) {
        classie.add(header, "smaller");
      } else {
        if (classie.has(header, "smaller")) {
          classie.remove(header, "smaller");
        }
      }
    });
  }
  window.onload = init();
</script>
</head>



<body>

  <div id="wrapper">

    <header>
      <div class="container clearfix">
        <h1 id="logo">
          Pratik
        </h1>
        <nav>
          <a href="">Lorem</a>
          <a href="">Ipsum</a>
          <a href="">Dolor</a>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </header>
    <!-- /header -->

    <div id="main">
      <div id="content">
        <section>
          <div class="container">
            <h1>Header Resize On Scroll with Animations</h1>
            <p>Cupcake ipsum dolor sit amet lollipop. Macaroon candy cotton candy bear claw macaroon carrot cake pastry icing dessert. Cupcake pastry tart sesame snaps lollipop donut pie. Cookie apple pie toffee lemon drops jelly beans cheesecake sweet roll.
              Jelly-o soufflé donut candy canes wafer dragée sweet cheesecake. Macaroon caramels pie cookie gummi bears. Ice cream jelly-o toffee cookie gingerbread cookie. Soufflé fruitcake jelly-o jelly chupa chups jelly beans. Dragée marzipan pastry
              macaroon oat cake muffin soufflé topping liquorice. Jelly-o chocolate cake lollipop.</p>
            <p>Sugar plum muffin cookie pastry oat cake icing candy canes chocolate. Gummi bears chupa chups fruitcake dessert jelly. Muffin cookie ice cream soufflé pastry lollipop gingerbread sweet. Unerdwear.com bonbon candy marzipan bonbon gummies chocolate
              cake gummi bears powder. Unerdwear.com tart halvah chocolate cake dragée liquorice. Sugar plum chocolate bar pastry liquorice dragée jelly powder. Jelly tootsie roll applicake caramels. Marzipan candy tootsie roll donut. Gummies ice cream
              macaroon applicake.</p>
            <p>
              <a href="https://www.facebook.com/pratik.chauhan.cp">« Connect With Me | Chauhan PRatik</a><br>
              <a href="http://bootsnipp.com/cppratikcp">« Go back to all tutorials?</a>
            </p>
          </div>
        </section>
        <section class="color">
          <div class="container">
            <h1>Cupcakes for the people!</h1>
            <p>Cupcake ipsum dolor sit amet lollipop. Macaroon candy cotton candy bear claw macaroon carrot cake pastry icing dessert. Cupcake pastry tart sesame snaps lollipop donut pie. Cookie apple pie toffee lemon drops jelly beans cheesecake sweet roll.
              Jelly-o soufflé donut candy canes wafer dragée sweet cheesecake. Macaroon caramels pie cookie gummi bears. Ice cream jelly-o toffee cookie gingerbread cookie. Soufflé fruitcake jelly-o jelly chupa chups jelly beans. Dragée marzipan pastry
              macaroon oat cake muffin soufflé topping liquorice. Jelly-o chocolate cake lollipop.</p>
            <p>Sugar plum muffin cookie pastry oat cake icing candy canes chocolate. Gummi bears chupa chups fruitcake dessert jelly. Muffin cookie ice cream soufflé pastry lollipop gingerbread sweet. Unerdwear.com bonbon candy marzipan bonbon gummies chocolate
              cake gummi bears powder. Unerdwear.com tart halvah chocolate cake dragée liquorice. Sugar plum chocolate bar pastry liquorice dragée jelly powder. Jelly tootsie roll applicake caramels. Marzipan candy tootsie roll donut. Gummies ice cream
              macaroon applicake.</p>
          </div>
        </section>
        <section>
          <div class="container">
            <h1>Chocolate, vanilla, and red velvet</h1>
            <p>Cupcake ipsum dolor sit amet lollipop. Macaroon candy cotton candy bear claw macaroon carrot cake pastry icing dessert. Cupcake pastry tart sesame snaps lollipop donut pie. Cookie apple pie toffee lemon drops jelly beans cheesecake sweet roll.
              Jelly-o soufflé donut candy canes wafer dragée sweet cheesecake. Macaroon caramels pie cookie gummi bears. Ice cream jelly-o toffee cookie gingerbread cookie. Soufflé fruitcake jelly-o jelly chupa chups jelly beans. Dragée marzipan pastry
              macaroon oat cake muffin soufflé topping liquorice. Jelly-o chocolate cake lollipop.</p>
            <p>Sugar plum muffin cookie pastry oat cake icing candy canes chocolate. Gummi bears chupa chups fruitcake dessert jelly. Muffin cookie ice cream soufflé pastry lollipop gingerbread sweet. Unerdwear.com bonbon candy marzipan bonbon gummies chocolate
              cake gummi bears powder. Unerdwear.com tart halvah chocolate cake dragée liquorice. Sugar plum chocolate bar pastry liquorice dragée jelly powder. Jelly tootsie roll applicake caramels. Marzipan candy tootsie roll donut. Gummies ice cream
              macaroon applicake.</p>
          </div>
        </section>
        <section class="color">
          <div class="container">
            <h1>Come to me!</h1>
            <p>Cupcake ipsum dolor sit amet lollipop. Macaroon candy cotton candy bear claw macaroon carrot cake pastry icing dessert. Cupcake pastry tart sesame snaps lollipop donut pie. Cookie apple pie toffee lemon drops jelly beans cheesecake sweet roll.
              Jelly-o soufflé donut candy canes wafer dragée sweet cheesecake. Macaroon caramels pie cookie gummi bears. Ice cream jelly-o toffee cookie gingerbread cookie. Soufflé fruitcake jelly-o jelly chupa chups jelly beans. Dragée marzipan pastry
              macaroon oat cake muffin soufflé topping liquorice. Jelly-o chocolate cake lollipop.</p>
            <p>Sugar plum muffin cookie pastry oat cake icing candy canes chocolate. Gummi bears chupa chups fruitcake dessert jelly. Muffin cookie ice cream soufflé pastry lollipop gingerbread sweet. Unerdwear.com bonbon candy marzipan bonbon gummies chocolate
              cake gummi bears powder. Unerdwear.com tart halvah chocolate cake dragée liquorice. Sugar plum chocolate bar pastry liquorice dragée jelly powder. Jelly tootsie roll applicake caramels. Marzipan candy tootsie roll donut. Gummies ice cream
              macaroon applicake.</p>
          </div>
        </section>
        <section>
          <div class="container">
            <h1>Sugar rush, oh my...</h1>
            <p>Cupcake ipsum dolor sit amet lollipop. Macaroon candy cotton candy bear claw macaroon carrot cake pastry icing dessert. Cupcake pastry tart sesame snaps lollipop donut pie. Cookie apple pie toffee lemon drops jelly beans cheesecake sweet roll.
              Jelly-o soufflé donut candy canes wafer dragée sweet cheesecake. Macaroon caramels pie cookie gummi bears. Ice cream jelly-o toffee cookie gingerbread cookie. Soufflé fruitcake jelly-o jelly chupa chups jelly beans. Dragée marzipan pastry
              macaroon oat cake muffin soufflé topping liquorice. Jelly-o chocolate cake lollipop.</p>
            <p>Sugar plum muffin cookie pastry oat cake icing candy canes chocolate. Gummi bears chupa chups fruitcake dessert jelly. Muffin cookie ice cream soufflé pastry lollipop gingerbread sweet. Unerdwear.com bonbon candy marzipan bonbon gummies chocolate
              cake gummi bears powder. Unerdwear.com tart halvah chocolate cake dragée liquorice. Sugar plum chocolate bar pastry liquorice dragée jelly powder. Jelly tootsie roll applicake caramels. Marzipan candy tootsie roll donut. Gummies ice cream
              macaroon applicake.</p>
          </div>
        </section>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- #main -->


    <footer>
      <div id="info-bar">
        <div class="container clearfix">
          <span class="all-tutorials"><a href="http://bootsnipp.com/cppratikcp">← all tutorials</a></span>
          <span class="back-to-tutorial"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/pratik.chauhan.cp">CHUAHAN PRATIK</a></span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- /#top-bar -->
    </footer>
    <!-- /footer -->



  </div>
  <!-- /#wrapper -->
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside the h1 tag (id logo) you should add an anchor tag and inside that an img tag. Now h1 should finally look like this.

```
<h1 id="logo">
    <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43962426/how-to-add-logo-image-in-this-bootstrap-snippet">
         <img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-hacSR6K2ogk/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAABU/hNHzed5piBU/photo.jpg?sz=32" alt="Pratik Home">
    </a>
    Pratik
</h1>
```